# error is coming in this line os.path.exists()

Tags: python

i am getting an error like below when I am trying to search the server after adding the server .

Linux server

```
while(h):
        ch= raw_input("""####################################
1.Search
2.Add
3.Edit 5.Exit
####################################
""")
        print(ch)
        if "1" in ch:
                a=''
                ser1 = raw_input ("Enter Server Name Which You Want To Search:")
                print(ser1)
                a=('/opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/'+ ser1 +'.txt')
                print(a)
                c=os.path.exists(a)
                print(c)
                if q == c:
                        aa=('/opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/'+ ser1 +'.txt')
                        #print(aa)
                        file=open(aa,"r")
                        re=file.read()
                        print(re)
                else:
                        print("Server Not Found Kindly Check...")
        elif "2" in ch:
                ser = raw_input ("Enter Server Name :")
                print(ser)
                x=( ser +'.txt')
                print(x)
                v=os.path.exists(x)
                print(v)
                if q != v:
                        d3 = ('/opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/'+ ser +'.txt')
                        fi = open(d3, "w+")
                        fi.write('Server Name :' +ser +'\n')
                        app = raw_input ("Enter Server Is Blowing To Which Application :")
                        print(app)
                        fi.write('Server Is Blowing To Which Application :' + app +'\n')
                        ser_os = raw_input ("Enter Server is in Unix/Windows :")
                        print(ser_os)
                        fi.write('Server is in Unix/Windows :' + ser_os +'\n')
                        ser_db = raw_input ("Enter The DB Server :")
                        print(ser_db)
                        fi.write('DB Server :' + ser_db +'\n')
                        db_type = raw_input ("Enter The Type Of DB :")
                        print(db_type)
                        fi.write('Type Of DB :' + db_type +'\n')
                        os = raw_input ("Enter The OS :")
                        print(os)
                        fi.write('OS :' + os +'\n')
                        sup = raw_input ("Enter The Support / Functional Team/SPOC :")
                        print(sup)
                        fi.write('The Support / Functional Team/SPOC :' + sup +'\n')
                        ven = raw_input ("Enter The Vendor Support(Yes/No) :")
                        print(ven)
                        fi.write('The Vendor Support(Yes/No) :' + ven +'\n')
                        ven_det = raw_input ("Enter The Vendor Details :")
                        print(ven_det)
                        fi.write('The Vendor Details :' + ven_det +'\n')
                        fi.close()
                        print("Server Added Successfully...")
                else:
                        print("Server Already Present Kindly Check...")
        elif "3" in ch:
                print("Edit")
        elif "4" in ch:
                ser2 = raw_input ("Enter Server Name Which You Want To Retire:")
                print(ser2)
                y=( ser2 +'.txt')
                print(y)
                g=os.path.exists(y)
                print(g)
                if q == g:
                        d3 = ('/opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/'+ ser2 +'.txt')
                        fi = open(d3, "w+")
                        r_comm = raw_input ("Enter The Comment For Retirement :")
                        print(r_comm)
                        fi.write('Comment For Retirement :' + r_comm +'\n')
                        fi.close()
                        cmd1 = 'mv /opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/'+ ser2 +'.txt /opt/Projects/avo_user_error/Inv/Retire/'
                        #print(cmd1)
                        os.system(cmd1)
                        print("Server Retirement Completed...")
                else:
                        print("Server Not Found Kindly Check...")
        elif"5" in ch:
                exit()
                print("Thany You...")
        else:
                print("Please Choose Correct Option...")
```

it should search the server and display the details. below is the error msg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Inv.py", line 32, in 
    c=os.path.exists(a)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'path'

Comment: It's extremly hard to read this unformatted code. Could you wrap it in code braces (triple backticks) and check line returns ?

Comment: This does not appear to be a [mre].

Comment: `os = raw_input ("Enter The OS :")`. You probably meant ***ser\_os***.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks it's working... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have overwritten the package name `os` with a variable name : `os = raw_input ("Enter The OS :")`.

Therefore, when you later call the function `os.path.exists`, python is trying to look for an attribute of the variable `os` that you created, and not for the `os` package function.

You should rename your `os` variable into something different like `ser_os` as @CristiFati suggested.

In general, it is good practice to avoid naming variables with Python modules names like `os`, `time`, or with reserved names like `lambda`, `in`, `with`...